# Why is Entity Framework (Core) deleting old records on Add() operation?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an entity that needs history tracked on it for employee pay rates.  The employeeRate object is:

```
public class EmployeeRate : BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeRateId { get; set; }

    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public double Rate { get; set; }
}

public class BaseEntity
{
    public bool ActiveFlag { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreateStamp { get; set; }

    public DateTime UpdateStamp { get; set; }

    public string LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

So to track history, when I "update" an employees rate, I retrieve all old records with their Id and set the ActiveFlag to false, then add a new entity with the new pay rate and the ActiveFlag set to true.  Here is my function for this operation:

```
private EmployeeRate UpdateRate(EmployeeRate model, string currentUser)
{
    var existingRates = _context.EmployeeRates.Where(r => r.EmployeeId == model.EmployeeId).ToList();
    foreach(var rate in existingRates)
    {
        rate.ActiveFlag = false;
        rate.UpdateStamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
        rate.LastModifiedBy = currentUser;
    }
    _context.SaveChanges();

    var newRate = new EmployeeRate()
    {
        EmployeeId = model.EmployeeId,
        Rate = model.Rate,
        ActiveFlag = true,
        CreateStamp = DateTime.UtcNow,
        UpdateStamp = DateTime.UtcNow,
        LastModifiedBy = currentUser
    };

    newRate = _context.EmployeeRates.Add(newRate).Entity;
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return newRate;
}
```

When I do an Add operation on my DbContext object, the SQL being generated by EntityFramework is deleting all old records for that employee for some reason.
Generated SQL:

> DELETE FROM `employeerates` WHERE `EmployeeRateId` = @p0;
>
> INSERT INTO
>   `employeerates` (`ActiveFlag`, `CreateStamp`, `EmployeeId`,
>   `LastModifiedBy`, `Rate`, `UpdateStamp`) VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4,
>   @p5, @p6); SELECT `EmployeeRateId` FROM `employeerates` WHERE
>   ROW_COUNT() = 1  AND `EmployeeRateId`=LAST_INSERT_ID();

Why would this be happening?  Is there a way to keep EF from deleting these old records?

**EDIT**

I am using asp.net core and entity framework core.

Comment: I don't understand the line `newRate = _context.EmployeeRates.Add(newRate).Entity;`... everything else looks fine. How does `BaseEntity` looks like?

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing `SaveChanges` twice here?

Comment: @Marc I've edited my post for BaseEntity.  Sorry, i tried to simplify it for the sake of the post before but made it more confusing ;)  that line of code in question is simply adding the newRate object to the EmployeeRates DbSet and then assigning the returned entity back to new rate so that the generated Id is populated when _context.SaveChanges() is called

Comment: @stephen.vakil, i thought for some reason that the update operation may have been causing SQL issues if it wasn't committed before I ran the Add.  I proved this wrong however, because I ran it with the entire update portion commented out and I get the same result

Comment: All, I think it may be an issue with having two of the same "EmployeeId" values in two different rows.  If I manually add a few records to the DB with the same EmployeeId as the one I'm adding, it will delete all of them.  Which is weird, because the generated SQL is deleting based on "EmployeeRateId"

Comment: How is the relationship between EmployeeRate and Employee? If there are any...

Comment: `_context.EmployeeRates.Add(newRate)` is enough to get the generated Id in `newRate`. About the question: at which `SaveChanges` call does the delete occur?

Comment: What is the .Entity at the end of this call: newRate = _context.EmployeeRates.Add(newRate).Entity;?  As @Gert Arnold suggested you only need to use .Add

Comment: @GertArnold, I should have said this is Entity Framework Core.  I'm sorry, I'll update my description.  But in Core, you have to use .Entity to get the entity back.

Comment: @Marc, the relationship between EmployeeRate and Employee is one to many.  An Employee can have many EmployeeRates, but only one is marked with the ActiveFlag at a time.  This is to track history of rate changes.

Comment: Could it be because you are calling `_context.SaveChanges();` twice? Once after you update the existing data and then after you add the new rows. What happens if you remove the first call and only submit after you've made all the changes/additions?

Comment: @ChrisF, I have tried commenting out the existingRates portion and the first _context.SaveChanges() and I get the same behavior.

Comment: Hmm. EmployeeRateId is the key - is that defined as the primary key and Identity Specification set in the database? (I know that it's an obvious question, but you have to check these things).

Comment: @ChrisF EmployeeRateId is set as the primary key for the EmployeeRates table.  I'm not sure what you mean by identity specification.  I am using MySQL if that helps

Comment: @big_water I mean that the database set (and increments) the key value so you don't have to.

Comment: @ChrisF ok, yes it is set to auto increment EmployeeRateId

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prepare to call me stupid...

Because of how I want to track history on the EmployeeRate object, I was thinking of my relationships between Employee and EmployeeRate incorrectly.  Here was my original Employee object (which I should've posted originally):

```
    public class Employee : BaseEntity
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        public int HomeLocationId { get; set; }




        //Navigation Properties
        public virtual Location HomeLocation { get; set; }

        public virtual EmployeeRate EmployeeRate { get; set; }
    }
```

Some of you may see the problem right away here.  The EmployeeRate reference actually has to be this:

```
public virtual List<EmployeeRate> EmployeeRates { get; set; }
```

because it is actually a one to many relationship.  Due to how I was thinking about only having to have one rate per employee, I only had the singular reference before (making it one to one as far as EF is concerned).  So when I updated the reference, EF thought it was one to one so it deleted all other records with the same reference.  It's actually "One to Many" with only ONE rate "Active" at a time.  So the EmployeeRate navigation property needs to be referenced as a List or Collection for EF to work properly and not delete old records.  Stupid me ;)

Comment: I had a similar situation. I wanted to add two entities with the same UserId but I had One-To-One relationship. Thank you.